# Sympy and Wolframalpha give different result

Tags: python, sympy, integral, wolframalpha

Sympy and wolframalpha have produced different result. Have done anything obviously wrong here?

```
import sympy as smp
smp.init_printing()
In [2]:

a,R,t = smp.symbols('a,R,t',real=True)
In [3]:

f = t**2/(1+t**2/a**2);f
Out[3]:
```

[image]

```
In [4]:
I=smp.Integral(f,t); I
Out[4]:
```

[image]

```
In [5]:
I.doit()
Out[5]:
```

a<sup>2</sup>t

Wolframalpha gives however

[image]

Comment: It looks like sympy simplifies the function by removing the a^3 tan-1(x/a) term. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in SymPy: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13501) about it. Meanwhile, a workaround is to declare `a` to be positive rather than just real. The sign does not matter anyway since `a` is squared, but I guess knowing that it's positive helps SymPy make the correct branch cut in the complex plane, or something like that.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> a = symbols('a', positive=True)
>>> t = symbols('t', real=True)
>>> integrate(t**2/(1+t**2/a**2), t)
a**2*(-a*atan(t/a) + t)
```

Using `integrate(expr, var)` here, which is easier to type than  `Integral(expr, var).doit()`.

Comment: Is there any place that I can find a list of known bugs in sympy 1.1.1?

Comment: The [issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) would be it, but it's not separated by version.

Answer (score -1):

Sympy currently cannot compute indefinite integrals. It computes

```
$$\(\int_{x_0}^{x} f(x)dx\)$$
```

The [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/holonomic/uses.html) has more details.

A great free tool on par with wolfram alpha is [sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/)
Check out their [online platform](https://cocalc.com/) where you can work and store your worksheets in the cloud.

Comment: nice answer. you can use this pic instead of raw latex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyMfT.gif

Comment: Even with limits 0 to x the integral is not what it produced.